# Seg. fault resizing array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, resize, fault

I have a priority queue array that is filled with "Jobs" (name + priority). I've been able to get everything queue related working aside from re sizing if it is full. Here is the bits that I think are causing a segmentation fault that I haven't been able to figure out.

EDIT:

Here is a bit more code that will compile, I left in the rest of the functions in case those might help in any way. Right now the initial capacity is set to 5, when you try to add a job to the full list it will double the capacity of the array and allow you to add a couple more jobs before a SEG. fault.

pq.h

```
#ifndef PQ_H
#define PQ_H
#include "interface.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Job {
    public:
        int getPriority();
        string getTaskName();
        void setPriority(int val);
        void setTaskName(string tname);
        Job();
    private:
        int priority;
        string taskName;
};

class PriorityQueue {

    public:
        PriorityQueue();
        ~PriorityQueue();
        int size();
        bool isEmpty();
        void clear();
        void enqueue(string value, int priority);
        string dequeue();
        string peek();
        int peekPriority();
        PriorityQueue(const PriorityQueue & src);
        PriorityQueue & operator=(const PriorityQueue & src);

    private:
        static const int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 5;  
        Job *array;
        int count;
        int capacity;

    void expandCapacity() {
        Job *oldArray = array;
        capacity *= 2;
        array = new Job[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            array[i] = oldArray[i];
        }
        delete[] oldArray;
    }
};

#endif
```

pq.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
//#include "job.h"
#include "pq.h"

Job::Job() // Constructor
 {
    priority= 0;
    taskName = "There are no items in the list.";
}

int Job::getPriority(){ // returns the prority of the job
    return priority;
}
string Job::getTaskName(){ // returns the name of the job
    return taskName;
}
void Job::setPriority(int val){ // sets the priority of a newly created job
    priority = val;
}
void Job::setTaskName(string tname){ // sets the name of a new job
    taskName = tname;
}

PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue() // constructor
    {
        count = 0;
        capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY - 1;
        array = new Job[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
        }

PriorityQueue::~PriorityQueue() { // destructor
   delete [] array;

}

int PriorityQueue::size() { // returns the number of jobs in the queue
   return count;  
}

bool PriorityQueue::isEmpty() { // returns true if queue is empty
   if (count != 0){
       return false;
   }else{
   return true;
   }
}

void PriorityQueue::clear() { // clears queue of all jobs
   count = 0;
   // need to make it remove and delete the items
}

void PriorityQueue::enqueue(string value, int priority) { 
   // tests size to see if Queue is a max capacity
   if(count == capacity){
       expandCapacity();
       cout << "\tList was full and has been expanded\n";
   }
   array[++count].setPriority(priority);
   array[count].setTaskName(value);

   // upheap operations
   Job v = array[count];
   int tempcount = count;
   while (array[tempcount/2].getPriority() >= v.getPriority()){
       array[tempcount] = array[tempcount/2];
       tempcount = tempcount/2;
   array[tempcount] = v;
   }

}
string PriorityQueue::dequeue() { 
    // removes the job with the highest priority from the queue and returns the name

    if(this->isEmpty()){ // make sure the queue isnt empty
        string empty = "The queue is empty";
        return empty;   
    }else{
   Job remove = array[1];
   array[1] = array[count--];

   int j;
   Job v;
   int k = 1;
   v = array[k];
   while(k <= count/2){
       cout << "dequeuewhile"; //  test
       j = k + k;
       if(j < count && array[j].getPriority() > array[j+1].getPriority()){
           j++;
           cout << "dequeueloop if1"; // test
       }
       if(v.getPriority() <= array[j].getPriority()){
           cout << "dequeueloop if2"; //test
           break;
       }
       array[k] = array[j];
       k = j;
   }
   array[k] = v;

   return remove.getTaskName(); //  returns the name of the removed job
    }
}
string PriorityQueue::peek() { // returns the name of the highest priority job without removing it from the queue
    if(count == 0){
        return array[0].getTaskName();
    }
   return array[1].getTaskName();
}

int PriorityQueue::peekPriority() { // returns the priority from the highest priority job without removing it from the queue
        if(count == 0){
        cout << "\tThere are no items in the list.\n";
        return array[0].getPriority();
    }
   return array[1].getPriority();
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  As it stands now, your `expandCapacity` has several flaws, one being that you change member variables (`capacity`) before calling `new[]`.   If `new[]` throws an exception, your `PriorityQueue` object would be corrupted.  The other issue being that your `PriorityQueue` class does not follow the rule of 3.  If a copy of a `PriorityQueue` is made anywhere in your program, the behavior is undefined.  Why not just use `std::vector<Job> array` instead of `Job* array`?

Comment: I did the best I could with the example, I'm really not sure what is going wrong. Capacity changes so that a new array with 2x the size is made to replace the old one. I am not able to use vectors for this.

Comment: You could have corrupted memory before `expandCapacity` is called.  You should really do as stated and post a [mcve].

Comment: Let's say that `capacity` is 1, and let's assume you initialized `count` to 0, thus the array has `capacity` elements.   The capacity is not increased since `count < capacity`.  So you increment `count`, and then you try to access `array[1]`, but `array[1]` is out of bounds.  So unless you show us what `count` is set to, right there is the mistake.  I know you set the initial capacity to 5, but instead, set it to 1, and you should see where your code fails.

Comment: I've edited in what I hope is an acceptable example.

Comment: Set `INITIAL_CAPACITY` to 2.  Then run this 4 line main function: `{ PriorityQueue pq; pq.enqueue("abc", 1); pq.enqueue("def", 2); pq.enqueue("123", 3); }`  -- This crashes right where the answer given to you is describing.  Note that you don't need to introduce menus or fancy input routines to test your code.  This is how you should have tested your class(es), using hard-coded data, exercising the functions in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code did exactly as the previous answer given by @antiHUMAN.

The problem you're having is mixing or erroneously using 0-based and 1-based concepts.

Your first mistake is to make `capacity` a 0-based number.  The `capacity` should denote the maximum number of items in an array, thus you should not be subtracting 1 from it.   If the array can hold 5 items, then `capacity` should be 5, not 4.

```
PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue() // constructor
{
    count = 0;
    capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;  // this remains 1-based.
    array = new Job[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
}
```

or using the initializer-list:

```
PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue() : count(0), 
                                 capacity(INITIAL_CAPACITY), 
                                 array(new Job[INITIAL_CAPACITY]) {}
```

---

The 0-based number in your situation should be `count`, not `capacity`.  Given that, since `count` is 0-based, and `capacity` is 1-based, your test in `enqueue` needs to be changed:

```
   if(count + 1 == capacity){
        expandCapacity();
        cout << "\tList was full and has been expanded\n";
    }
```

Note that 1 is added to count to account for the fact that `count` is 0-based and `capacity` is 1 based.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help, using the `if(count + 1 == capacity)` works but it seems like it causes the array to expand sooner than necessary. If the `initialCapacity = 2` the array ends up expanding before the first entry instead of before the second.

Comment: Well, note that when you add an item to your array, you could never populate item 0.  `array[++count].setPriority(priority);`  -- The `count` is incremented to 1, so `array[0]` can never get populated or changed.  That again is a 0-based, 1-based issue, what `capacity` really means (everything except item 0, or is that included?) you need to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you do `++count`, the next use of `count` will be out of bounds for the array.

```
array[++count].setPriority(priority);
// SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
array[count].setTaskName(value);
```

If the capacity of the array is 5, and `count` was 4, then you just incremented `count` to 5, and tried to access element 5, which is out-of-bounds.

```
 array = new Job[capacity];
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     array[i] = oldArray[i];
 }
```

Lets assume `capacity` is 10, so you've got an array of 10 elements, ranging from elements 0 to 9.
`count`tells us how many elements are being used.
If `count` happens to be `9`, then when you increment `count` by one, it is now `10`. Then, when line come you marked as producing segment fault comes, you're trying to access element `10`, in our example. There is no element `10`in an array of length `10`, so you're out of bounds.

```
array[++count].setPriority(priority); // array[10], but last element is 9!
// SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
array[count].setTaskName(value); // array[10], but last element is 9!
```

And, of course, everything after that part causes the same issue, as you keep using `array[count]`.

Comment: The count keeps track of the highest index with data in it, so incrementing it before hand should just say where to place the next priority, then name. Also, it checks the capacity before that and doubles it. I only get the error after I try to increase the capacity.

Comment: @Drakorex We don't know what `count` is initialized to.  It could be anything with the code you (so far) posted.

Comment: @Drakorex You do a check to see if count == capacity, right? As I understand it, "capacity" is the length of the array. If "count" is just one less than capacity, then *after* you check whether count == capacity (to increase capacity), you increment "count" so that it *is* equal to capacity. So, as it would seem to me, if the array length is 5, then you're trying to access element 5. But there is no element 5 in an array of length 5. The last element is element 4. Tell me if I'm being an idiot, here. :/

Comment: The user "PaulMcKenzie" seems to agree with me, as he comments the exact same thing, I see.

Comment: I posted a better example, in my constructor capacity is set to 1 less than the initialCapacity constant that should prevent it from trying to add past the last element. It is also successful at making enlarging the array but breaks after adding into it again a few times.

Comment: @Drakorex The error is exactly what the answer given you is describing. If you don't believe it, why not print out the value of count right after this line: `array[++count].setPriority(priority);` -- You should clearly see that count is beyond the bounds of your array after you've called expandCapacity(). Note that arrays start from index 0 and go to `n - 1`, where `n` is the total number of items. I think you're forgetting about the `- 1` part of this issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
`capacity = initialcapacity - 1;` should account for that right? I only get these errors after introducing the `expandCapacity` function. I understand what you mean and it would be an issue if I weren't expanding the array right before accessing what used to be out of bounds.